# how to overload << operator to output a vector that is a member of a class

Tags: c++, class, vector, overloading

I'm trying to use the << operator to output vectors that are private members of my class.

The compiler won't let me access the vectors directly as they are private, but it also won't let me access public member functions that return the vectors.

How do I make the << operator output all the contents of a private member vector?

This is my class:

```
class Name_pairs
{
    public:

    Name_pairs      (){}

    //....



    vector<string> Names       (){return names;      }
    vector<double> Ages        (){return ages;       }
    vector<double> Sorted_ages (){return sorted_ages;}


private:

    //....
    vector<string> names;
    vector<double> ages;
    vector<double> sorted_ages;
};
```

This is the overloaded << function:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Name_pairs & n)
    {
        return os<< n.Names(); //won't let me access
            return os<< n.names.size(); //won't let me access 

    }
```

This is the print function that I'm trying to replace by overloading the << function:

```
void Name_pairs:: print_name_age  ()
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "These names and ages are now sorted" << endl;

        for(int index = 0; index <  names.size(); ++index)
            {
            cout << "index " << index << ": " << names[index]<< " is age: " << sorted_ages[index] <<endl;
            }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`n.Names()` returns a vector and you can't print vectors directly through a standard `operator <<` method. You have to iterate through the vector and print its elements.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Name_pairs& n)
{
    if (!os.good())
        return os;

    auto names = n.Names();
    std::copy(names.begin(), names.end(),
                             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os));
    return os;
}
```

Comment: std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os)); When I put this code into my << function the compiler is giving me an error is telling that "std has no member iostream_interator". Does your answer suggest that for the << operator to work with a vector the vector must be copied into the "os" object? Is there any other way?

Comment: @user2904033 Include the `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>` header.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
return os<< n.Names(); //won't let me access
```

doesn't work, because you're trying to write a **whole vector** at once, instead of it's elements, and `ostream` doesn't provide an overloaded `operator <<` for the `std::vector`. The solution is just writing elements from the `vector`, that's being returned by this function.

```
for(int i=0;i<n.Names().size();i++)
   cout << n.Names()[i];
```

**As a side note**: you probably don't want to use your version with large vectors, since (unless your compiler is smart enough to make the function inline), will consume a lot of time to return the whole vector. Try returning a **const reference** to the vector, instead of the vector itself.